# How do I fix this error while running expo build android?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

**Hello, I need some help. So what's the case is I am trying to build an android apk from my expo react app. But when I try to do so, it fails. This is the output that is being shown when trying to run 'expo build:android'. It works fine when run on expo client on android. Please help me. The code for this project is in [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/SetuCoder/Story-Hub).**

```
✔ Choose the build type you would like: › apk
Checking if there is a build in progress...

Accessing credentials for setucoder in project storyhub5
✔ Would you like to upload a Keystore or have us generate one for you?
If you don't know what this means, let us generate it! :) › Generate new keystore
Failed to generate Android Keystore, it will be generated on Expo servers during the build
keytool exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: keytool exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:439:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:673:12)
    ...
    at spawnAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
    at createKeystore (/@expo/xdl@59.0.14/src/credentials/AndroidCredentials.ts:155:18)
    at Object.generateUploadKeystore (/@expo/xdl@59.0.14/src/credentials/AndroidCredentials.ts:198:9)
    at UpdateKeystore.provideOrGenerate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/credentials/views/AndroidKeystore.ts:68:53)
    at UpdateKeystore.open (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/credentials/views/AndroidKeystore.ts:39:22)
    at CredentialsManager.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/credentials/route.ts:41:12)
    at runCredentialsManager (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/credentials/route.ts:12:10)
    at AndroidBuilder.collectAndValidateCredentials (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/build/AndroidBuilder.ts:88:7)
    at AndroidBuilder.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/build/AndroidBuilder.ts:33:5)
    at AndroidBuilder.command (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/build/BaseBuilder.ts:40:7)
```

Comment: This issue got addressed by the expo team and is resolved [https://forums.expo.io/t/can-update-app-in-playstore-problems-with-signing-and-
fingerprint/31520/4](https://forums.expo.io/t/can-update-app-in-playstore-problems-with-signing-and-fingerprint/31520/4)

Comment: here is another option for hope this will solve your problem https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob#user-content-http-data-transfer

Answer (score 7):

## Solution - March 2021 (on macOs - Big Sur)

### Error `keytool exited with non-zero code: 1`

[image]

Install the latest `Java SE Development Kit`

- Found here https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Installing JAVA SE 15 fixed this issue. I think the key tool has something to do with java**

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue with expo's `turtle build:android` command in my azure devops CI/CD pipeline(Running on macOs). After a searching a bit more on this issue, I figured out the following.

The actual issue is the android build environment's JDK version should match the version of the JDK you have used while generating the `keystore.jks` file using `keytool`.
As of today(18-Nov-2021), the latest JAVA SE version was 17. If I use this latest version of SDK to generate keystore file, that couldn't be decrypted with build environment's JDK (which is not latest). I have generated the `keystore.jks` file with JAVA SE 15. It worked for me.